# Как опустить сайдбар под контент?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Есть такая простенькая тема WP https://wp-themes.com/burger-factory/. Почему-то сайдбар в мобильной версии отображается вверху, а не внизу, под контентом. Подскажите, как можно убрать сайдбар со всем его содержимым под контент в мобильной версии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняем местами элементы

`1:<div class="col-9 archive-entry-list"></div>`

`2:<div class="col-3 sidebar"></div>`

прописываем в стилях первому float:right;

[image: Меняем местами элементы, добавляем float:left]

P.S. Может это и не мое дело, но лучше использовать flex-box, а не float

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Один странный момент - когда прописываешь float:right, а после перемещаешь дивы, они странным образом зеркалятся, то есть при float:right сайдбар слева, при float:left - справа. Не сталкивался с таким.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, рабочий вариант таков, что нужно переместить весь сайдбар в правую сторону, тогда на мобильной верстке сначала будет идти контент, потом сайдбар
Сейчас так:

```
<div class="col-3 sidebar">...</div>
<div class="col-9 archive-entry-list">...</div>
```

А надо так:

```
<div class="col-9 archive-entry-list">...</div>
<div class="col-3 sidebar">...</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.